# Como usar o SelniunHQ para preencher formulários com o php?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

estou a dias sem dormir..rs , tentando resolver um problema que me parecia simples...Tenho dados em um banco de dados e preciso disparar esses dados para outro site preenchendo os campos oriúndos do banco de dados e submetelos...
Estava tentando fazer com curl, mas um colega me disse que o correto é fazer com seleniunHQ, alguém sabe como usar o seleniun para automatizar o cadastro de um  formulário como se fosse um robo?
Esse trabalho é para atender uma agência, onde tenho que colher os dados de uma landing page e popular outra...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua pergunta está muito ampla, no entanto, vou tentar ajudá-lo.

Você pode usar uma combinação de: `Python` + `Selenium` para navegar e popular os formulários. Se precisar colher informações das páginas abertas, pode também utilizar a biblioteca `BeautifulSoup` para extrair as infos.

---

Para iniciar o navegador:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Para abrir uma URL:

```
driver.get("www.url.com")
```

Para encontrar e preencher um campo com o valor `"MeuNome"`:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="primeiro_nome"]')
text.send_keys('MeuNome')
```

Para pressionar o botão de continuar:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="btn_continuar"]')
button.click()
```

Para colher os dados de uma página, você pode criar uma `soup` com o conteúdo da página aberta no webdriver do selenium:

```
html_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')
```

---

Após criar um banco de dados com as informações a serem preenchidas, pode criar uma estrutura de repetição para preencher as páginas a cada iteração:

```
for reg in registros:
    nome = reg[0]
    sobrenome = reg[1]
    aniversario = reg[2]
    nickname = reg[3]

    abre_pagina()

    preenche_dados()

    finaliza_cadastro()
```